# integral $\sqrt{x+2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+2}}$

Tags: integration

$\sqrt{x+2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+2}}$, when i do the integral i get:

$$2/3\sqrt{(x+2)^3}+2\sqrt{x+2}$$

but wolfram [gives me a different result](http://bit.ly/16AWYKA), how?:

$$\frac23\sqrt{x+2}(x+5)+C$$

Comment: $(x+5)=(x+2) + 3$

Comment: Please keep the question self-contained. Copy what Wolfram alpha gives as the answer, don't give a link.

Comment: As it is, WA is just giving a different form for the same answer.

Comment: Since $x+2\ge0$, $\sqrt{(x+2)^3}=(x+2)\sqrt{x+2}$.

Comment: But i'd like to know how to reach it

Comment: You can do one of four things when the answer you get from an integral doesn't match the answer in the back of the book (ABB).
1. try to factor your answer and see after some simplifying it does come to the ABB, or simplify the ABB.
2. subtract your answer from the ABB then, simplify; if you get a constant, they were both good answers
3. derive your answer, simplify and verify if you came back to the function you were integrating
4. plot both answers and see if the graphs are parallel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5Bx%2B2%5D%2B1%2FSqrt%5Bx%2B2%5D%2Cx%5D

gives the result $$\int \sqrt{x+2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+2}} \, dx = \frac{2}{3}(x+5)\sqrt{x+2} + C.$$  This is equivalent to your answer, since $$\frac{2}{3}(x+5)\sqrt{x+2} = \frac{2}{3}((x+2)+3)\sqrt{x+2} = \frac{2}{3}(x+2)^{3/2} + 2\sqrt{x+2}.$$

Wolfram|Alpha will attempt to simplify the antiderivative it calculates to reduce the `LeafCount`.  If you take your antiderivative and factor it, you get the same answer.

---

From your antiderivative:  $$\begin{align*} \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{(x+2)^3} + 2 \sqrt{x+2} &= \frac{2}{3} (x+2)^{3/2} + 2(x+2)^{1/2} \\ &= \frac{2}{3} \left( (x+2)^{3/2} + 3(x+2)^{1/2} \right) \\ &= \frac{2}{3}\left((x+2)(x+2)^{1/2} + 3(x+2)^{1/2} \right) \\ &= \frac{2}{3}\left( (x+2) + 3 \right) (x+2)^{1/2} \\ &= \frac{2}{3}(x+2)^{1/2} (x+5). \end{align*}$$

Comment: i still don't get how you go between these 2:
$\frac{2}{3}((x+2)+3)\sqrt{x+2} = \frac{2}{3}(x+2)^{3/2} + 2\sqrt{x+2}$.

Comment: @Christian $(x+2)\sqrt{x+2}=(x+2)(x+2)^{1/2}=(x+2)^{1+1/2}=(x+2)^{3/2}$.

Comment: I still don't get it. $(x+2)\sqrt{x+2}=(x+2)^{3/2}$ .
So what i get is: $2/3(x+2)\sqrt{x+2}+2\sqrt{x+2}$.
I don't know where that 5 is from. I don't have any $(x+2)+3$

Comment: What i have is: $\sqrt{x+2}(2/3)(x+4)$

Comment: I finally got it, omg. Thanks.